# Group arrays in my object on a specific value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to group the arrays in my object on a specific value. Even after seeing documentation online and studying similar question on Stackoverflow I can't find the answer of my problem.

For exemple I have this object :

```
const myList = [
{
  name: "task 1",
  mission: {
   id: 1,
   name: "mission #1",
   ...
  }
},
{
  name: "task 1",
  mission: {
   id: 3,
   name: "mission #2",
   ...
  }
},
{
  name: "task 2",
  mission: {
   id: 6,
   name: "mission #4",
   ...
  }
},
{
  name: "task 2",
  mission: {
   id: 19,
   name: "mission #3",
   ...
  }
}, 
...]
```

What is the best way in js to group by name my object and transform this object to :

```
const myNewList = [
{
  name: "task 1",
  mission1: {
   id: 1,
   name: "mission #1",
   ...
  },
  mission2: {
   id: 2,
   name: "mission #2",
   ...
  }
},
{
  name: "task 2",
  mission3: {
   id: 3,
   name: "mission #3",
   ...
  }, 
  mission4: {
   id: 4,
   name: "mission #4",
   ...
  }
}, 
...]
```

Thank you by advance for any help.

Comment: You sure you want unique names for `mission` in results? That's not very code friendly as opposed to an array like `missions: [ {id:3, name:...}, {id:4,name:...}]`. Then each group has same "missions" property

Comment: Hello this is just for an easy exemple. Actually I am using it in an object like this : ```{ description: "", Admin: { //multiple value }, Reader: { //multiple value }, Editor: { //multiple value } }```

Comment: So what would a "multiple value" look like? Still probably want arrays there not objects. Incrementing `mission_1` -> `mission_x` doesn't seem practical

Comment: Try lodash.groupBy

Answer (score -2):

```
const myNewList = myList.reduce((res, item) => {
  const group = res.find(i => i.name === item.name);
  if (!group)
    res.push({name: item.name, mission1: item.mission});
  else {
    const attrName = `mission${Object.keys(group).length}`;
    group[attrName] = item.mission;
  }
  return res;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution. However the key ```mission``` is only an exemple. My keys are ```Adminstrator : { id: 1, action: "all" } / Reader : { id: 2, action: "read" } / Editor { id: 3, name: "edit" }```.

Comment: The answer builds exactly the structure you provided. Please post a more detailed example of input and output arrays to help us understand your challenge